# Rshiny: Reduce bottom padding shiny dashboard box

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Attached is `shiny::selectInput` within a `shinydashboard::box`, the following is the code in Rshiny:

```
box(selectInput(inputId = "test", label = "Normalization", choices = 'RSEM: FPKM'), width = 3, background = 'navy')
```

How do I change the box padding such that the bottom navy blue portion is reduced?

[image]

I tried increasing it using the css:

```
.box {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

and it increase the bottom to this:

[image]

But when I try to decrease it, it doesn't change a bit:

```
.box {
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

Comment: use `.form-group {margin-bottom: 0px;}` instead

Comment: @HubertL This did not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `form-group` and `selectize-control` both have bottom margins that you can remove. If you want to completely get rid of the box padding, you can also remove the bottom padding of the `box-body`.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody( tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      .form-group, .selectize-control {
           margin-bottom: 0px;
      }
      .box-body {
          padding-bottom: 0px;
      }'))),
      box(selectInput(inputId = "test", label = "Normalization", choices = 'RSEM: FPKM'), width = 3, background = 'navy') )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```